# Why am i getting assertion error of FirebaseAppService

Tags: firebase, ember.js, ember-data, emberfire

Version info

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember      :  3.4.4
DEBUG: Ember Data : 3.11.0
DEBUG: EmberFire  : 3.0.0-rc.3
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

Steps to reproduce
Try to save record on my firebase storage in controller:

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
import v4 from 'npm:uuid/v4'

export default Controller.extend({
  emailFromValue: '',
  header: 'Coming soon',
  alertMessage: '',
  showAlert: false,
  isDisabled: computed('emailFromValue', function() {
    return !this.emailFromValue.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/);
  }),
  actions: {
    changeEmailValue({ target: { value } }) {
      this.set('emailFromValue', value);
    },
    requestInvitation(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      this.store.createRecord('invitation', { id:v4(), email: this.emailFromValue}).save()

      this.set('alertMessage',`Thank you! We saved your email address: ${this.emailFromValue}`)
      this.set('showAlert', true)
    }
  }
});
```

config of firebase in environment:

```
firebase: {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyAhO6f8wKS-...",
      authDomain: "...9e.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "...39e.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "...39e",
      storageBucket: "",
      messagingSenderId: "...45128",
      appId: "...94d4964176"
    },
```

Expected behavior
Successful save the data

Actual behavior
after calling save method of record i've got an error:

```
index.js:163 Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You must call `this._super(...arguments);` when overriding `init` on a framework object. Please update <libraries-app@service:firebase-app::ember204> to call `this._super(...arguments);` from `init`.
    at assert (index.js:163)
    at FirebaseAppService.__ASSERT_INIT_WAS_CALLED__ember1565768194366642062813808__ (object.js:88)
    at sendEvent (metal.js:462)
    at initialize (core_object.js:107)
    at Function.create (core_object.js:692)
    at FactoryManager.create (container.js:549)
    at instantiateFactory (container.js:359)
    at lookup (container.js:287)
    at Container.lookup (container.js:131)
    at Class.lookup (container_proxy.js:78)
```

How have i already tried to solve it:

- Installed different versions of emberfire and ember-cli, but had another issues
- Searched error in google and github issues, but haven't got any result

Comment: Are you using any init fuction?  If so please add this  `this._super(...arguments);` to your init function.

Comment: no, i don't use any init hooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same thing happened to me yesterday (your question was 6 hours old). Since your ember data is 3.11 im going to assume that your ember-source is also 3.11.

Fixed it by changing `"ember-source" "~3.10"` from 3.11.1

Then I deleted my node_modules directory and ran `npm install` again.

My GUESS is the warning is because something new was added in 3.11